# Android ContentResolver.insert() throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, insert, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to add some audio files ( m4a, mp3, ... ) to MediaStore's audio collection, so that other music apps can list them. To keep it simple I just copied what the documentation says.
( https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media )

So in the activities onCreate() method I wrote this:

```
val resolver = applicationContext.contentResolver

val audioCollection =
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(
            MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY
        )
    } else {
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    }

val songDetails = ContentValues().apply {
    put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "Test Track")
}

resolver.insert(audioCollection, songDetails)
```

But every time I start it, I get the following:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.lastIndexOf(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1972)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1934)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1593)
```

The manifest declares the READ, WRITE as well as the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and enabled these storage permissions in the android app settings on my device.

Comment: Display name with valid extension please.

Comment: Ah, yes of course.

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```kotlin
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), "Test Track").absolutePath)
}
```

to your `songDetails`.

##### Explanation

I stumbled upon this issue on Android 6. It is not reproducible on Android 12 though. I had a little investigation and found out that Android 6 has a bug trying to get path from `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA` (actually it is `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA` but they all refer to the same column) and use it.

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-6.0.0_r41:packages/providers/MediaProvider/src/com/android/providers/media/MediaProvider.java;l=3105

As you can see from the source code, if the value of `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA` is null, `MediaProvider` produces `NullPointerException`.

From documentation of [`MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns#DATA) you are not allowed to write to this column directly on Android 11 and above hence the `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)` condition.